# Overwriting ant property from custom ant task

Tags: java, ant

So the overall problem is this:

We have multiple property files

```
<property file="prop1"/>
<property file="prop2"/>
```

prop1 contains a property looking like:

```
mg.prop = ${mg2.prop}
```

prop2 contains mg2.prop

```
mg2.prop = Hello
```

If they were in the same file and I queried mg.prop, I'd get "Hello" back. Since they are in separate files this does not work (I need to load prop1 before prop2!)

I wrote a custom ant task that does the following:

```
String resolved = resolveProperty(propertyName);
getProject().setProperty(propertyName, resolved);
```

If I run

```
log("Resolved property value = " + getProject().getProperty(propertyName));
```

Right after, I get the correct value.

However in the Ant script, if I do

```
<echo message="${mg.prop}"/>
```

it shows me the original value.

Any thoughts on how to solve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's how I ended up resolving this - I turfed the custom ant task.

I ended up concatenating all the properties files into one, in the reverse order of precedence.

So if I wanted properties from 3.properties to override those in 2.properties and 1.properties, I did the following:

```
<concat destfile="resolved.properties">
    <fileset file="1.properties" />
    <fileset file="2.properties" />
    <fileset file="3.properties" />
</concat>

<property file="resolved.properties"/>
```

Answer (score 3):

From the Ant manual:

"Properties are immutable: whoever sets a property first freezes it for the rest of the build; they are most definitely not variables."

http://ant.apache.org/manual/Tasks/property.html

Depending on your situation, you might be able to accomplish what you want by loading prop1 **twice**, using `loadproperties` and a filter chain that the first time takes only lines *not* containing "{mg2.prop}", and the second time takes only lines that *do* contain it.

http://ant.apache.org/manual/Tasks/loadproperties.html
http://ant.apache.org/manual/Types/filterchain.html#linecontains

Comment: Thanks Russell - I did see this in the manual, I just thought that a custom task could resolve that :) wrongly, apparently. I did solve it using a different method - see below.

Answer (score 2):

You can also use the [var task](http://ant-contrib.sourceforge.net/tasks/tasks/variable_task.html) of [ant-contrib](http://ant-contrib.sourceforge.net/) to reset values.

From the doc:

> The next example shows a property being set, echoed, unset, then
>   reset:
>
> ```
> <property name="x" value="6"/>
> <echo>${x}</echo>   <!-- will print 6 -->
> <var name="x" unset="true"/>
> <property name="x" value="12"/>
> <echo>${x}</echo>   <!-- will print 12 -->
> ```